# Avisos SonarQube en java

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

Buenos días compañeros desarrolladores, tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar, soy nuevo en este mundillo del desarrollo, llevo 3-4 meses programando y aun estoy un poco verde, así que si veis alguna burrada espero me perdonéis. Me han encomendado solucionar problemas de SonarQube, después de solucionar algunos sencillos tengo dos que se repite decenas e incluso cientos de veces, estos dos son los errores que tengo que mas se repiten:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salta el error en "session", "request", "valor" y "auxService".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este otro me sale en "session", "request", "entorno" y "valor".

He intentado yo poner el "Serializable" en el implements como veis, pero no ha solucionado nada...

Os pongo un ejemplo de mi codigo donde dice que debo implementar estos cambios.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Controller("cacUtil")
public class CacUtil extends BaseAction implements SessionAware, Serializable {

    /* CAMPOS */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, Object> session;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private String entorno;
    private InputStream valor;


    /* SERVICES */
    @Autowired
    private GestionAuxiliaresService auxService;


    /* METODOS */
    public String cacSesionCookie(){

        try{
            valor = new ByteArrayInputStream( auxService.getCacSesionCookie( recuperarEntorno() ).getBytes() );         
        }catch(Exception e){
            LoggerApl.error("CacUtil", "cacSesionCookie", e);
            valor = new ByteArrayInputStream( "".getBytes() );
        }

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    /* UTILIDADES */
    private String recuperarEntorno(){

        Cookies cookies = new Cookies(request);
        return cookies.getCookie(request);      

    }

    /* GETs & SETs */
    public GestionAuxiliaresService getAuxService(){
        return auxService;
    }
    public void setAuxService(GestionAuxiliaresService auxService){
        this.auxService = auxService;
    }

    public String getEntorno(){
        return entorno;
    }
    public void setEntorno(String entorno){
        this.entorno = entorno;
    }

    public InputStream getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public void setValor(InputStream valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
```

Muchas gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 1):

El primer error, como bien has hecho debería solucionarse implementando Serializable. Asegurate de que el sonar te esté filtrando el código nuevo y no el antiguo.

Por otro lado en el segundo error te dice que tus variables deberían autowirearse. Para eso deberías definir un bean con estas clases y después autowirearlas. Además, tampoco está demás, en el caso de los mapas, sus valores en un PostConstruct. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
@Bean
public Map<Object, Object> getMapa() {
  return new HashMap<>(Object.class);
}

@Autowired
private Map<Object, Object> mapa;

@PostConstruct
private void setMap() {
  ...
   // Insertar valores en el mapa
  mapa.put(key, value);
  ...
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario y tu ayuda. El primer error no se soluciona poniendo seriazable en el implements, para els egundo voy a intentar la solucion que me propones y te comento.